# Register multiple WebJobs in Azure from code

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs, azure-sdk-.net

I need some advice about Azure WebJobs.

I want to dynamically add WebJobs to the Azure App Service of my Web Application. Each WebJobs contains the same function with a different parameter i want to give it. Based on the parameter it pings to a different web-URL. Each job needs to reoccur tho a dedicated Cron-schedule.

Is it possible to do this from code? I can find documentation about adding WebJobs etc but can't find information about the subject of registering **multiple** Azure Jobs **from code**.

Thanks in advance.

Greetings,

Wouter